# New format for logs: numbered lines WITH automatic line breaks

Tags: feature-request, formatting

IMHO serverfault shoul support yet another format for quoting code/logs: numbered lines with line breaks.  It would allow to see whole lines without horizontal scrolling with preserved **important** information about original line breaks.

```
1:  line-1A
    line-1B
    line-1C
2:  line-2A
    line-2B
```

Comment: Also of note [Some discussion on this in Chat, and thoughts on alternative solutions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13777786#13777786)

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a Bad Idea to me - at least if it's intended to *replace* the existing code block format.

My main objection is it breaks the ability to cut and paste from a code block to your terminal: If you cut and paste something with the above formatting it is virtually guaranteed ***NOT*** to work (it can be "fixed" of course, but reassembling the original text would require at minimum some scripting. That's asking a lot of people...).

My secondary objection is that without a quantum leap in AI technology it's impossible to intelligently break lines in all of the possible "stuff" that gets put in code blocks: Doing so requires context awareness that the site doesn't have ("Is this a log file? An error message? A C program? A shell script? Python? Perl? Ruby?")

---

The Right Thing (IMHO) is for whoever is posting this data to properly format it for us (break long lines themselves). This isn't that much effort - I'd say it's the minimum we should expect from someone asking a question ("Make your question *readable*"), or posting an answer ("Break long lines sensibly so your answer is *readable*").

I don't really object to this as an *additional* format, though I doubt people would be using it much (the markdown formatting options are already numerous enough that most people don't know them all) and I don't personally see the need for it either (again I feel the onus is on the person posting to make their post *readable*)

Comment: I see the need for the additional format **mainly** for log files.  I think the format may be handy for code in **some** (rare) cases.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Sounds like you really want a "Log File" syntax highlighting type with trimmings then (IDK if syntax highlighting can do more than just highlight but that'd be a less painful implementation path if it can...)